# Can 'endear' be used for inanimate objects?

Tags: word-usage, usage

Can "endear" be used for a country or some other inanimate object? For example is 'I have come to endear my country.' correct?

Comment: _endear my country_ to what? _endear myself to my country_ is perhaps what you are looking for.

Comment: Following @user405662, another possiblity would be "my country has endeared itself to me". It's not clear from your question whose affections are being increased.

Comment: I was going to add that. Thank you, @user888379.

Comment: To endear is either intransitive or reflexive.

Answer (score 2):

The use of ***endear*** is particular, as you can see from [dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03KnZc3Ioagt-IUh6o0CthKZ88oow%3A1608727219148&ei=szrjX93aCMaAhbIPhaSD8Ag&q=endear%20meaning&oq=endear%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIICAAQBxAKEB46BAgAEEc6BwgjELACECc6BAgAEA1QlltY4l5g3mJoAHADeACAAUyIAcsBkgEBM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwidgMDzj-TtAhVGQEEAHQXSAI4Q4dUDCA0&uact=5) available online. It means

> `cause to be loved or liked.`
>
> Example: Flora's spirit and character ***endeared*** her ***to*** everyone who met her.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/endear) agrees:

> `If something endears you to someone or if you endear yourself to them, you become popular with them and well liked by them.`

I would rather say

> I have come to ***cherish*** my country.